# PHP result from mySQL doesn't show quotes inside input value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using "mysql_real_escape_string" to insert the data into mySQL.

To retrieve it, I echo it by using stripslashes, and it works fine, except, when I put the value inside of an input's value like in this example. The single quotes work fine, Example: Milky's Home... But the double quotes, cut the script, in the first quote:. Example: Milky's "Home" would should only: Milky's

If I remove the stripslashes, it shows: Milky/'s /

So, still cuts it in the first quote.

This is the script:

```
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[id]);

<?
echo stripslashes($Titlez['titlez']);
?>
<input type="text" size="150px" name="titlez" value="<? echo stripslashes($Titlez['titlez']); ?>">
```

I also tried these 2 options, but give the same result:

```
<?
$titlez = stripslashes($Titlez['titlez']);
echo '<input type="text" size="150px" name="titlez" value="'.$titlez.'">';
echo "<input type=\"text\" size=\"150px\" name=\"titlez\" value=\"".$titlez."\">";
?>
```

Comment: You should stripslashes() on the incoming data, before it's saved to the database.  Also, as you're discovering, magic quotes are really bad.  If you can, then turn them off.

Comment: I would recommend you to transition your code to PDO, use prepared statements, then it will protect you from MySQL injection. With PDO you should not care about mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$titlez = htmlentities(stripslashes($Titlez['titlez']));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the data into the input must use `htmlentities()`, it will take care for the double quotes.

http://php.net/htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use mysql_real_escape_string for anything but inserting data into MySQL.   Also, once the data is stored in the DB, the slashes (or whatever is used to escape special characters) added by mysql_real_escape_string are removed, so when you pull the data from the DB, you shouldn't need to use "stripslashes" or any other un-escape method.

As others have already mentioned, you will want to disable Magic Quotes in your php.ini if you haven't already.  Otherwise, extra slashes will be added to any request data automatically.

Once you embed the data into your HTML, you will then use htmlentities, as mentioned by Rezigned, to properly escape special characters.

Comment: Thank to all, I easily found the php.ini in the folder MAMP/conf/php5.2/php.ini I opened it with a text editor and changed magic_quotes_gpc = On to Off

Comment: @GordonM But How can I modify it in the server. It's a VPS, in ISPconfig I saw this /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini but in FTP I don't see a way to get there.